# Unable to decrypt AES gcm 256 for tls 1.2 using Python

Tags: python, c, openssl, tls1.2

I am trying to change the C code below to Python for functionality, but I have not received the correct results and I am not sure where the problem lies
Firstly, the C code

```c
    ctx = OPENSSL_malloc(sizeof(EVP_CIPHER_CTX));
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(ctx);
    c = EVP_get_cipherbyname(SN_aes_256_gcm);
    
    ret = EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx, c, NULL, key, NULL, (which & SSL3_CC_WRITE));
    if(ret == -1) return 1;
    ret = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IV_FIXED, 4, iv);
    if(ret == -1) return 1;
    dump_str("ctx iv", ctx->iv, 12);
    memcpy(buf, &seq, sizeof(long));
    buf[8] = type;
    buf[9] = (unsigned char)(version >> 8);
    buf[10] = (unsigned char)(version);
    buf[11] = len >> 8;
    buf[12] = len & 0xff;
    dump_str("buf", buf, 13);
    ret = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, 22, 13, buf);
    //printf("EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl %d\r\n", ret);
    if(ret == -1) return 1;
    dump_str("enc", enc, len);
    ret = EVP_Cipher(ctx, enc, enc, len);
    //printf("EVP_Cipher %d\r\n", ret);
    if(ret == -1) return 1;
    dump_str("nors", enc, len);
    dump_str("nor", enc + 8, len - 8);
```

The relevant parameters are as follows

```
enc:742d3775849dbe54cd35f70c42df452185ad27c819e1ee9106802f74f4d4abd5905ffd047dfd19a8

key:5FC67C85CA6AA4E79F034F277EA9F710F915BAE314A7E04D1DE1F326D25F3CD8

iv:5251251ED83828792E7684A75CA78403

ctx iv:5251251E0000000000000000

buf:00000000000000001603030028

plaintext:1400000C21F3D8A6DEE21AE9B96A563806802F74F4D4ABD5905FFD047DFD19A8
```

The Python code is as follows. I don't know where the problem is, please help me

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
key = bytes.fromhex('5FC67C85CA6AA4E79F034F277EA9F710F915BAE314A7E04D1DE1F326D25F3CD8')
data = bytes.fromhex('742d3775849dbe54cd35f70c42df452185ad27c819e1ee9106802f74f4d4abd5905ffd047dfd19a8')
iv = bytes.fromhex('5251251E0000000000000000')
additional_data = bytes.fromhex('000000000000001603030028')
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=iv)
cipher.update(additional_data)
plaintext = cipher.decrypt(data)
print(plaintext[8:].hex())
```

I tried several AES decryption methods in Python, but none of them succeeded in meeting expectations，
Expected results：plaintext:1400000C21F3D8A6DEE21AE9B96A563806802F74F4D4ABD5905FFD047DFD19A8

Comment: What was `enc`?

Comment: Sorry, it's my problem enc is 742d3775849dbe54cd35f70c42df452185ad27c819e1ee9106802f74f4d4abd5905ffd047dfd19a8

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the C code. First, I tested using your plaintext and the official documentation on [pycryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/aes.html) page.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import binascii

key = bytes.fromhex('5FC67C85CA6AA4E79F034F277EA9F710F915BAE314A7E04D1DE1F326D25F3CD8')
iv = bytes.fromhex('5251251E0000000000000000')
plaintext = bytes.fromhex('1400000C21F3D8A6DEE21AE9B96A563806802F74F4D4ABD5905FFD047DFD19A8')

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=iv)
ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(plaintext)

decipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=iv)
decrypted_plaintext = decipher.decrypt(ciphertext)

print("Original plaintext:", plaintext.hex())
print("Ciphertext:", binascii.hexlify(ciphertext).decode())
print("Decrypted plaintext:", decrypted_plaintext.hex())
```

Output:

```
Original plaintext: 1400000c21f3d8a6dee21ae9b96a563806802f74f4d4abd5905ffd047dfd19a8
Ciphertext: d80bdbbbed3be74c3a7b8cb3a6f38500401259d02e5145c82a5a2a30ef9565bc
Decrypted plaintext: 1400000c21f3d8a6dee21ae9b96a563806802f74f4d4abd5905ffd047dfd19a8
```

Then, I replaced the correct encoding `"d80...5bc"` in the OP's code, instead of the `enc` which the OP is using now:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
key = bytes.fromhex('5FC67C85CA6AA4E79F034F277EA9F710F915BAE314A7E04D1DE1F326D25F3CD8')

# OP's enc
# data =  bytes.fromhex('742d3775849dbe54cd35f70c42df452185ad27c819e1ee9106802f74f4d4abd5905ffd047dfd19a8')

# Corrent enc
data = bytes.fromhex('d80bdbbbed3be74c3a7b8cb3a6f38500401259d02e5145c82a5a2a30ef9565bc')

iv = bytes.fromhex('5251251E0000000000000000')
additional_data = bytes.fromhex('000000000000001603030028')
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=iv)
cipher.update(additional_data)
plaintext = cipher.decrypt(data)
print("Decrypted Plaintext:", plaintext.hex())
```

As expected, it outputs the intended plaintext:

```
Decrypted Plaintext: 1400000c21f3d8a6dee21ae9b96a563806802f74f4d4abd5905ffd047dfd19a8
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for answering . Secondly, I'm sorry that my expression may not be very clear The complete plaintext is 742D3775849DBE541400000C21F3D8A6DEE21AE9B96A563806802F74F4D4ABD5905FFD047DFD19A8 C language did not print the first 8 digits of data，Meanwhile, this is decryption based on openssl tls 1.2，I attempted to convert it to a Python implementation, but I failed

Comment: Still the same, if i replace the correct enc for "742...A8" using AES into your code, which is "b826ecc2485581be29ac61565d469619c33f516cc364008cbc85f84066bcd7c1fc92bf65679138e8" I get the desired plaintext 742...A8

Comment: If you can provide your end to end working C code, i can look into it, why it does not produce the same encoded text, currently is a super difficult to guess what are different variables in the C code

Comment: still does not compile. lots of errors like: .c:5:5: error: unknown type name ‘EVP_CIPHER_CTX’
    5 |     EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C.c:6:5: error: unknown type name ‘EVP_CIPHER’
    6 |     EVP_CIPHER* c;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
C.c:13:22: error: ‘SSL_MAX_MASTER_KEY_LENGTH’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   13 |     unsigned char hb[SSL_MAX_MASTER_KEY_LENGTH] = { 0 };
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Yes, I have updated the C code, and this is the complete C code. The first half calculates the "key extension" and extracts information such as keys and iv. "additional_data" is connected according to RFC5246. Finally, thank you very much for your help me

Comment: not sure what was updated; i cant see any changes! doesnt matter what half does what, the code should compile if we want to get a reproducible code to debug. For instance, here i tried your code on an online compiler for review: https://onecompiler.com/c/3zdpm57cx; doesnt compile, too many new environment variables; please check or provide details on how to compile

Comment: Yes, you may not be able to compile directly. Above is the entire processing logic. The calculation of the "Key Extension" section has been completed, and the rest is the decryption of AES GCM 256. I'm not sure if this will help you. I'm really sorry, I'm here https://onecompiler.com/c/3zdpmmzmt After writing all the code, compile the command: "gcc tool. c - I/root/openssl-1.0.1c/include/root/openssl-1.0.1c/*. a - ldl". You may also need to download some files and so on

Comment: I see, not sure if I can fix it then; :) let me know if i should delete this answer, since the answer only verifies that python encryption/decr works so the error/discrepancy is in the C code. otherwise, I will let it be there for some future reader,

Comment: This is your right, of course you can choose to delete it. Thank you very much for helping me

Comment: No worries, hope someone fixes the C part as well. Good luck!

Comment: thank you for your help. I also wish you a happy life